# Autosys Job : Can we trigger a job on Email received event?

Tags: autosys

Can we start a autosys job based on subject line in email received in the mailbox configured for Autosys. Is this  possible and how can we setup such a autosys job.

Answer (score 0):

not possible for autosys itself. But quite easy for mail daemon. In this case question should be - how to execute a command (autosys sendevent) command upon receiving of the email message?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending that notification Email via Autosys job then Yes it is possible with the help of dependency else i dont think so it will be possible.

Long  story in short if you have a job which triggers this notification then on success of this notification email job you can trigger another job

job_name:sendEmail

job_name:emailAction
condition:s(sendEmail)

Thanks!